# Saída do meu serviço não condiz com a minha dto

Tags: c#, entity-framework, rest, asp.net-web-api

Na saída do meu serviço, para o campo DadosItens, tenho isso:

```
<DadosItens>
Qtde 3 Custo 46,66Unitario 68,58 Margem 0Ult.Cond 30/01/2017 C. Diario 46,66 Total 205,73
</DadosItens>
```

Acontece que eu não tenho nenhum Label Qtde ou Custo ou Margem ou qualquer outro em minha DTO que é o que eu exporto pelo serviço. Eu tentei sim, colocar esse labels, mas como estava dando erro, não no label, mas da forma que eu estava fazendo, removi-os e deixei apenas os campos. E depois que eu acertei tudo, fui rodar e está vindo assim e não sei onde ele está fixado(da primeira vez) para eu consertar isso, até porque não posso subir assim, porque não sei o que está acontecendo. Essa concatenação eu fiz, porque preciso jogar numa célula do meu App Xamarin.Forms esse campos todos juntos na mesma célula, pois o cliente quer assim e não estava conseguindo fazer na App e no forum do Xamarin, me deram essa dica. Essa é minha DTO

```
public class ItensLibDTO
    {
        public string Produto { get; set; }
        public string Qtde { get; set; }
        public string Unitario { get; set; }
        public string MargemAvista { get; set; }
        public string Custo { get; set; }
        public string CustoDiario { get; set; }
        public string UltCondicao { get; set; }
        public string Total { get; set; }
        public string DadosItens
        {
            get
            {
                return Qtde.ToString() + " " + Custo.ToString() + "  " + Unitario.ToString() +
                  " " + MargemAvista.ToString() + " " + UltCondicao.ToString() + "  " +
                  CustoDiario.ToString() + " " + Total.ToString();
            }
            set
            {
                Qtde = value;
                Custo = value;
                Unitario = value;
                MargemAvista = value;
                UltCondicao = value;
                CustoDiario = value;
                Total = value;
            }
        }
```

E minha classe para o serviço

```
public class ItensLiberacao
    {
        AutorizadorContext contexto = new AutorizadorContext();
        ItensLibDTO libDTO = new ItensLibDTO();
        CultureInfo minhaCultura = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");

        [Route("itens/{id}")]
        public List<ItensLibDTO> getItensLib(int id)
        {
            var lista = contexto.ItensLibs
                .Where(itens => itens.IdOrcamento == id)
                .Select(item => new ItensLibDTO
                {
                    Produto = item.Produto,
                    Qtde = item.Qtde.ToString(),
                    Unitario = item.Unitario.ToString(),
                    MargemAvista = item.MargemAvista.ToString(),
                    Custo = item.Custo.ToString(),
                    CustoDiario = item.CustoDiario.ToString(),
                    UltCondicao = item.UltCondicao.ToString(),
                    Total = item.Total.ToString(),
                    DadosItens = item.Qtde.ToString() + " " + item.Custo.ToString() + "  " + item.Unitario.ToString() +
                                 " " + item.MargemAvista.ToString() + "  " + item.UltCondicao.ToString() + "  " + item.CustoDiario.ToString() +
                                 " " + item.Total.ToString()
                }).ToList();

            lista.ForEach(e => e.UltCondicao = new DateTime(1800, 12, 28).AddDays(float.Parse(e.UltCondicao)).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));

            lista.ForEach(e => e.Unitario = string.Format(new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:N}", double.Parse(e.Unitario, new CultureInfo("en").NumberFormat)));
            lista.ForEach(e => e.Custo = string.Format(new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:N}", double.Parse(e.Custo, new CultureInfo("en").NumberFormat)));
            lista.ForEach(e => e.CustoDiario = string.Format(new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:N}", double.Parse(e.CustoDiario, new CultureInfo("en").NumberFormat)));

            lista.ForEach(e => e.Total = string.Format(new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:N}", double.Parse(e.Total, new CultureInfo("en").NumberFormat)));

            return lista;
        }
    }
```

Veja que eu não tenho nenhum label ou nome dos campos. Como falei havia feito assim da primeira vez, mas não rodou, estava com erros. Primeiro os removi pensando ser eles e depois vi que tinha a ver com o banco, aí deixei sem eles e agora está vindo assim. Como faço? Reinicio o PC, rs?

**EDIT1**

Sempre que dou um clean na solution tenho problemas. Resolveu com o clean, o problema dos "labels", mas está dando erro nessa linha e em todas que possuem lambdas semelhantes, ou seja, todos os foreach na classe ItensLiberacao. Essa linha foi apenas um exemplo.

```
lista.ForEach(e => e.UltCondicao = new DateTime(1800, 12, 28).AddDays(float.Parse(e.UltCondicao)).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

dizendo que a cadeia de caracteres é inválida. Pessoal, estava funcionando antes do **clean** e não sei mais o que está acontecendo, sinceramente. Se comento todos os foreach na classe itensLiberacao, aí o serviço sobe e sem os "labels".
Reinicieio VS e mesmo assim persiste o erro:

> A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato correto.

No meu site está funcionando com esse foreach, só não subi ainda com essas alterações.

**EDIT2**

Fiz assim agora

```
var lista = contexto.ItensLibs
                .Where(itens => itens.IdOrcamento == id)
                .Select(item => new ItensLibDTO
                {
                    Produto = item.Produto,
                    Qtde = item.Qtde.ToString(),
                    Unitario = item.Unitario.ToString(),
                    MargemAvista = item.MargemAvista.ToString(),
                    Custo = item.Custo.ToString(),
                    CustoDiario = item.CustoDiario.ToString(),
                    UltCondicao = item.UltCondicao.ToString(),
                    Total = item.Total.ToString()
                    //DadosItens = ""
                    //DadosItens = "Qtde " + item.Qtde.ToString() + " " + "Custo " + item.Custo.ToString() + "  " + "Uni. " + item.Unitario.ToString() +
                    //             " " + "Mar " + item.MargemAvista.ToString() + "  " + "Ul.Cond. " + item.UltCondicao.ToString() + "  " + "C.Dia " + item.CustoDiario.ToString() +
                    //             " " + " Total " + item.Total.ToString()
                }).ToList();

            lista.ForEach(e => e.UltCondicao = new DateTime(1800, 12, 28).AddDays(float.Parse(e.UltCondicao)).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));

            lista.ForEach(e => e.Unitario = string.Format(new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:N}", double.Parse(e.Unitario, new CultureInfo("en").NumberFormat)));
            lista.ForEach(e => e.Custo = string.Format(new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:N}", double.Parse(e.Custo, new CultureInfo("en").NumberFormat)));
            lista.ForEach(e => e.CustoDiario = string.Format(new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:N}", double.Parse(e.CustoDiario, new CultureInfo("en").NumberFormat)));

            lista.ForEach(e => e.Total = string.Format(new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:N}", double.Parse(e.Total, new CultureInfo("en").NumberFormat)));

            lista.ForEach(e => e.DadosItens = "Qtde " + e.Qtde.ToString() + " " + "Custo " + e.Custo.ToString());

            return lista;
```

Não deu mais o erro, mas o retorno do serviço repete todos os valores assim:

```
<ItensLibDTO>
<Custo>Qtde 3 Custo 46,66</Custo>
<CustoDiario>Qtde 3 Custo 46,66</CustoDiario>
<DadosItens>
Qtde 3 Custo 46,66 Qtde 3 Custo 46,66 Qtde 3 Custo 46,66 Qtde 3 Custo 46,66 Qtde 3 Custo 46,66 Qtde 3 Custo 46,66 Qtde 3 Custo 46,66
</DadosItens>
<MargemAvista>Qtde 3 Custo 46,66</MargemAvista>
<Produto>BASF CABRIO TOP 1KG LOTE: 158-15-4000 VAL 05/2017</Produto>
<Qtde>Qtde 3 Custo 46,66</Qtde>
<Total>Qtde 3 Custo 46,66</Total>
<UltCondicao>Qtde 3 Custo 46,66</UltCondicao>
<Unitario>Qtde 3 Custo 46,66</Unitario>
</ItensLibDTO>
```

Deveria ser assim

```
<ItensLibDTO>
<Custo>46,66</Custo>
<CustoDiario>46,66</CustoDiario>
<DadosItens>3 46,66 68,58 0 30/01/2017 46,66 205,73</DadosItens>
<MargemAvista>0</MargemAvista>
<Produto>BASF CABRIO TOP 1KG LOTE: 158-15-4000 VAL 05/2017</Produto>
<Qtde>3</Qtde>
<Total>205,73</Total>
<UltCondicao>30/01/2017</UltCondicao>
<Unitario>68,58</Unitario>
</ItensLibDTO>
```

**DadosItens** está comentado, tanto na **DTO** como na **classe do serviço**

Não sei de onde vem isso, se eu comentei esse campo tanto na DTO como na classe do serviço:

```
<DadosItens>3 46,66 68,58 0 30/01/2017 46,66 205,73</DadosItens>
```

Comment: O erro pode ser devido ao novo campo DadosItens, mas já chegou a funcionar, conforme indiquei no post e agora não funciona nada. Possivelmente alguma string, na transformação tá dando pau, mas alguém sabe como eu resolvo isso? Pelo que eu sei `ToString()`não garante nada.

Comment: O comando CLEAN limpa os pacotes anteriores que foi criado no seu build, a culpa não é do clean e sim de alguma alteração que você fez entre a chamada do comando. Esse erro é formatação incorreta nessa parte `float.Parse(e.UltCondicao)`, se ele não consegue fazer o parse essa exceção acontece.

Comment: @GabrielColetta, mas antes deu criar a property DadosItens, estava funcionando com esse parse e se comento os foreach, funciona também e se comento o DadosItens e deixo os foreach descomentados, também funciona. Só não funciona, com ambos habilitados.

Comment: Recomendo que você quebre esse lambda no foreach normal e vá debugando essa expressão, esta bem ilegível e não sei exatamente onde acontece essa exceção, ela pode acontecer nesse ToString também.

Comment: Comentou e continua vindo dados dele? Esse comportamento esta bem estranho, quando você diz "subo o serviço", você diz publicar o app?

Comment: Quando eu subo o serviço, eu pego pelo Postman ou pelo Browser(xml)

Comment: @GabrielColetta, o seguinte dei um clean na solution e esqueci de comentar apenas no me DTO o campo DadosItens. Quando subi o serviço, veio o campo com **nil**, ok normal. Comentei e quando eu subi, continuou vindo. Somente quando limpei a solution é que deixou de aparecer no Postman ou no Chrome(xml). Parece ser uma espécie de **cache** na aplicação, o ruim disso é que eu terei de estar fazendo sempre Clean na solution.

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi, mas do nada funcionou. dei alguns cleans. O colega Gabriel Colleta, me disse que nada a ver com o Clean, mas depois de dar alguns(uns 3), funcionou. Assim ficou meu código:
DTO

```
public class ItensLibDTO
    {
        public string Produto { get; set; }
        public string Qtde { get; set; }
        public string Unitario { get; set; }
        public string MargemAvista { get; set; }
        public string Custo { get; set; }
        public string CustoDiario { get; set; }
        public string UltCondicao { get; set; }
        public string Total { get; set; }
        public string DadosItens { get; set; }
    }
```

E o método que exporta para o serviço

```
public class ItensLiberacao
    {
        AutorizadorContext contexto = new AutorizadorContext();
        ItensLibDTO libDTO = new ItensLibDTO();
        //CultureInfo minhaCultura = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");

        [Route("itens/{id}")]
        public List<ItensLibDTO> getItensLib(int id)
        {
            var lista = contexto.ItensLibs
                .Where(itens => itens.IdOrcamento == id)
                .Select(item => new ItensLibDTO
                {
                    Produto = item.Produto,
                    Qtde = item.Qtde.ToString(),
                    Unitario = item.Unitario.ToString(),
                    MargemAvista = item.MargemAvista.ToString(),
                    Custo = item.Custo.ToString(),
                    CustoDiario = item.CustoDiario.ToString(),
                    UltCondicao = item.UltCondicao.ToString(),
                    Total = item.Total.ToString(),
                    DadosItens = ""
                }).ToList();

            lista.ForEach(e => e.UltCondicao = new DateTime(1800, 12, 28).AddDays(float.Parse(e.UltCondicao)).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));

            lista.ForEach(e => e.Unitario = string.Format(new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:N}", double.Parse(e.Unitario, new CultureInfo("en").NumberFormat)));
            lista.ForEach(e => e.Custo = string.Format(new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:N}", double.Parse(e.Custo, new CultureInfo("en").NumberFormat)));
            lista.ForEach(e => e.CustoDiario = string.Format(new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:N}", double.Parse(e.CustoDiario, new CultureInfo("en").NumberFormat)));

            lista.ForEach(e => e.Total = string.Format(new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:N}", double.Parse(e.Total, new CultureInfo("en").NumberFormat)));

            lista.ForEach(e => e.DadosItens = "Qtde " +  e.Qtde.ToString() + " " + "Uni. " + e.Unitario.ToString() + " " + "Marg. " + e.MargemAvista.ToString() + 
                          " " + "Custo " + e.Custo.ToString() + " " + "C.Dia " + e.CustoDiario.ToString() + " " + "U.Cond. " + e.UltCondicao.ToString() +
                          " " + "Total " + e.Total.ToString());

            return lista;
        }
```